# Possible for a child form to return a value to parent form and not an object?

Tags: forms, symfony

I see that Symfony2 always ties form types to objects, but is it possible to reuse a form type to where it can only be used as a child?

This is just an example of what I'm trying to accomplish, but I think it could apply to many scenarios.

First lets say I have the following entity:

```
class Person
{
    public function getState();   
    public function getHomeState();   
}
```

These two fields are choice fields of states.

I want that when a user selects a choice `getState()` and `getHomeState()` should only return a string.

Something like:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;


class PersonFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('State', 'statelist'),//statelist is a form service.
            ->add('HomeState', 'statelist')//use form service here too
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Person'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'person';
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is being able to reuse the form below.

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class StateListType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $ChoiceList;

    public function __construct(ChoiceListInterface $Choices)
    {
        $this->ChoiceList = $Choices;
    }
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        //Unsure what to do here to accomplish what I want. 
        $builder->add(?, 'choice', array('choice_list' => $this->ChoiceList);
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'statelist';
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't want the form above to be tied to any data class and just let me reuse the choices that would provide a string to the parent form.

So that I may easily do `$Person->getState()`, have the string and be done with it.

Right now if I were to use another `data_class` for the child form above lets say `Address`. Which contained a method of the same name `getState()`. The child form would return the `Address` object to the `getState()` method of `Person` and I'd have to access the data via `$Person->getState()->getState()` and `$Person->getHomeState()->getState()` respectively.

It just doesn't make sense (from a readability point of view) to do this and this applies to other similar use cases.

Is it possible to have a child form just return a string to it's parent form and not an object?

P.S.
I know I can just use the choice list alone but choice lists can't be made into a service. I have to 'wrap' the choice list class into a another form so that I can use the form as a service which allows greater flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can redefine a basic "string" field as "choice" without adding inner fields but simply overriding **setDefaultOptions**, a nice explanation about how **OptionResolverInterface** works is [here](http://symfony.com/blog/form-goodness-in-symfony-2-1)

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class StateListType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $ChoiceList;

    public function __construct(ChoiceListInterface $Choices)
    {
        $this->ChoiceList = $Choices;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver
            ->setDefaults(
                array(
                    'choices' => $this->ChoiceList,
                    'empty_value' => 'select a state'
                )
            );

    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'statelist';
    }
}
```

another instrument used to transform object to string(but usually is used to transform string to objects) is add a datatransformer to the field [datatransformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addViewTransformer($this->createTransformer());
}

/**
 * @return DataTransformerInterface
 */
protected function createTransformer()
{
    return new FieldTransformer($this->getRepository(), static::FIELD_NAME);
}
```

but i think this is another story. The important thing to understand is that if you add fields under a formtype your field will return an object (or an array i don't remember) and not a string

Comment: Thanks! Now on to the next issue... :) If you'd like to check it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705473/supplying-arguments-to-child-form-thats-a-service-from-a-parent-form