# Supplying arguments to child form thats a service from a parent form?

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm trying to make a child form more dynamic (besides already being highly reusable by making it a service) by providing parameters to it.

However I'm having trouble providing parameters to a choice class that the child form uses.

**TL;DR: The form `StateListType` inherits the `choice` parent. Is it possible to change/override the default 'choice_list' from the buildForm method inside `StateListType`?**

The comments in the following code explain what I'd like to do.

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class PersonFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('State', 'statelist'),//statelist is a form service.
            ->add('HomeState', 'statelist')//use form service here too
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Person'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'person';
    }
}
```

The following code is a form that the service container takes care of injecting the proper dependency to it.

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class StateListType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $ChoiceList;

    public function __construct(ChoiceListInterface $Choices)
    {
        //If I'm right I can't use another parameter
        //to call from the parent form since it's already a service?
        $this->ChoiceList = $Choices;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        //Don't usually need this method at all.
        //However if I need to provide arguments
        //I can set 'custom_argument'
        //in the setDefaultOptions method below.

        //Then I could use $options['custom_argument']
        //from the parent form to provide arguments to
        //$this->ChoiceList->doSomething($options['custom_argument')
        //and then replacing the default 'choice_list' with this?
        //Just not sure how or if even possible to do it from here.
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver
            ->setDefaults(
                array(
                    //Could use $arg this by getting options from the constructor.
                    //But since it's a service I can't supply dynamic arguments.
                    'choice_list' => $this->ChoiceList->doSomething($arg),//Returns itself after doing something.
                    'empty_value' => 'select a state',
                    'custom_argument' => null
                )
            );

    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'statelist';
    }
}
```

**Extra info as per request in the comments:**

Service:

```
StateListChoice:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Extension\StateListChoices

StateListType:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\Form\StateListType
    arguments: ["@StateListChoices"]
    tags:
            {name: form.type, alias: statelist}
```

Custom choice class:

StateListChoices.php

```
class StateListChoices extends LazyChoiceList implements ChoiceListInterface
{
    ...
    public function doSomething($argument)
    {
         //Does something with argument
         return $this; //Returns ChoiceListInterface object.
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: did you try `$builder->add('State', 'statelist', array('custom_argument' => 'your custom variable'));` ?

Comment: Can't do that since there's another method called `HomeState` under `PersonFormType'.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do ? you want to pass a custom state list to the statelist form ?

Comment: @Ramy I can already do that via `setDefaultOptions` using `choice_list`. Also without calling `buildForm` as well but I can't provide any arguments to `ChoiceList` from the parent form which is the problem.

Comment: I just noticed you're talking about the parent form. Yes I can pass the argument but how can I get `ChoiceList` to use it in the `StateListType` form?

Comment: can you add to the question the service definition of your forms as well as a full example of how you are currently building the form ( e.g. in your controller )

Comment: You can see in the constructor that the service is injecting a `ChoiceListInterface` object. Building the form isn't the problem, the problem is providing the `ChoiceList` an argument from the parent form `PersonFormType`.

Comment: I can do `$builder->add('State', 'statelist', array('custom_argument' => 'your custom variable'));` but there's no way (that I know) to use that variable inside `StateListType`.

Comment: If you do that, then in stateListType you can access that by $options['custom_argument'] in your `buildForm()`

Comment: where are the variable that you want to pass to the form? is it in an entity? a service? a model? I don't have enough information about what you want to achieve to help you.

Comment: Yes. But after that I want to use `$this->ChoiceList->doSomething($options['custom_argument')` which gives me my custom list... I don't know how to give this list to `StateListType` after I call it inside `buildForm`

Comment: I need to get more information to help you. I need to see the definition of the service to know what you are passing. And I need to know where you can access that variable you want to pass. I can't offer any solution with what I know now. I am sorry.

Comment: Ok, I added it as per your request. I feel like it will just make it more complicated but ok there it is.

Comment: Ok, things are clearer now. Last question .. what do you expect `$argument` to be? what would it contain where would you get that from? is it a property of `Person` entity or something?

Comment: `$argument` should be what we talked about. `$options['custom_argument']`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What do you want to it to contain? is it array? string? property of some class?

Comment: String. `$builder->add('State', 'statelist', array('custom_argument' => 'your custom variable'));` this example was fine. It's just a static string only for the form `PersonFormType`.

Comment: The point is that `doSomething` returns a Symfony2 `ChoiceListInterface` that `StateTypeList` form can use. I just don't know how I can change the `choice_list` inside `buildForm` or if it's possible.

Comment: If you're still confused I clarified my question in bold at the beginning of the page. That's the main thing I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If your `buildForm()` in `StateListType` I don't know why not just build the form in `PersonType` directly?

You can also define `PersonType` as a service:

```
PersonType:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\Form\PersonType
    arguments: ["@StateListChoices"]
    tags:
            {name: form.type, alias: person}
```

Then use the choices services there directly:

```
use Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Extension\StateListChoices


class PersonType extends AbstractType
{
    public function __construct(ChoiceListInterface $choicesList)
    {
        $this->choicesList = $choicesList;
    }

    private function getChoices($argument = null)
    {
        return $this->choicesList->doSomething($argument);
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
          $builder
            ->add('State', 'choice', array(
                'choice_list' => $this->getChoices($options['custom_argument']),
            ))
            ->add('HomeState', 'statelist', array(
                'choice_list' =>  $this->getChoices();
            ));
    }
```

Comment: Because I want to be able to use the choice as a service and not have to inject it to every form I want to use it besides `PersonFormType`.

Comment: I want `StateListChoices` to stay as a service though via the `StateListType` form.

Comment: it is a service still. what's the difference? anyway .. if you ever found it what you want to do, write it here for reference. Thanks.

Comment: I added it as a service. if that's what you want. Even though I believe it's exactly the same.

Comment: I want to be able to use it through the parent form builder parameters and not have it to inject every form I use it on.

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible because if not then I'll just use the traditional method.

Comment: either you let symfony init it as a service ( by injecting it ) or you can init it yourself by calling `new SomeClass()` ... I showed you both ways. I don't know what exactly are you looking for other than these two ways

Comment: The code that I showed works without both of those methods. I just don't know if there's a way to override the default `choice_list` inside `StateListType`.